# How to query auto set axis bounds in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I've created a plot and let bokeh choose the axis bounds automatically.  Now I want to know what the min and max values of that axis are (specifically because I want to overlay the plot of a mathematical function and want to know over what range to evaluate it).

The obvious approach was to query `fig.y_range.start` and `fig.y_range.end`, but it appears those are set to None when autoscaled, so they look like input parameters.

How do I determine what the results of autoscaling were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available in Python, those bounds are only computed in the browser, in JavaScript. If you need explicit details/control, you will need to set the ranges manually, e.g.

```
p = figure(x_range=(0, 137))
```